# Shazam for video

Tags: api, detection, image-recognition, shazam

I have recently been looking into music/video recognition APIs.

Shazam has proved very effective in recognising music, and there is an API called EchoNest that will allow music recognition to be integrated into apps.

I am however looking for an API that will detect movie/video information. Whilst I know these APIs exist (youtube uses such an API) but I am looking for something that is publicly available.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing as such available at this time publicly . You need to develop your own or you can use a trick. The trick is to play a song from the movie and use the api to recognize that song. Then you can automate the system (your software) to find which movie that song is from . This automation can be from Internet or your own database.

Answer (score 0):

We use https://runacr.com in our projects. They have SDK for iOS and Android.